# How can I find out which XSD is slow to load in Eclipse's XML validator

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, xml-validation

I'm working on a web project, but that project takes a long time to build in eclipse. The same project build very fast using the maven command line. The build steps that seem to take the longest time is the validation of XML files.

I understand when this step is slow, it is usually because eclipse cannot access one or more XML schemas fast enough. I know of the trick of using the XML catalog to make sure that eclipse doesn't try to re-download all the schemas all the time, but to make effective use of this, I need to know which one is slow to download. It's actually quite hard to figure it out since each schema may need to load other schemas.

The problem is, I don't know which schema is slow to load. Is there a way to activate some kind of debugging option that would print out the URL of each schema as it is being downloaded, (or as it fails to download, maybe)? I could then actually download that schema and insert it in the catalog.

Otherwise, is there a way to tell eclipse to cache the downloaded schemas, so that at least validation is only slow the first time?

I actually like the XML validation feature, so turning it off is my very last resort.

Comment: I'm not sure but schemas which are not in the catalog will be downloaded and cached, Preferences>General>Network Connections>Cache shows them. Validation seems to be using the cache...

Comment: @atlanto Yeah, that's also what I thought, but my cache is shown as empty in this screen, even though caching is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Install wireshark and look at the http requests. It should be pretty obvious which schema takes a long time to return. (Close your web browser when you're doing it)

If you can't install wireshark, try [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), and set the Eclipse proxy to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that because I don't have admin rights on my corporate issued machine...

Comment: Ok, so I used fiddler, and I can see that the DTD are actually being downloaded successfully (strangely only when fiddler is enabled), but that they do not seem to be cached. Whenever I save an XML file, I can see multiple DTD and XSD files being downloaded. How come my catalog doesn't seem to actually be used.